# Get sizeof anonymous struct inside union

Tags: c++, c, struct, sizeof, unions

I'm hoping this isn't a duplicate question, but I've searched in some detail and haven't found my exact case before.

I have a simple struct that I also want to be able to access as a simple byte array

```
union
{
  struct
  {
    unsigned char a;
    unsigned char b;
    // ... Some other members ...
    unsigned char w;
  };
  unsigned char bytes[sizeof( what? )];
} myUnion;
```

Notice the struct is not named and it also isn't given its own member name.  This is so that I can use `myUnion.a` to access that member, and not `myUnion.myStruct.a`.

However, without some name, how can I get the size of the struct for `myUnion.bytes[]` other than manually calculating it each time I change something?

My current workaround is to use a `#define` to make up for the `myUnion.myStruct` problem, but that has the negative side-effect of ruining my auto-complete in the editor, and also makes my data structures harder to understand.

Any ideas?

**Note:** This is running on an 8-bit processor.  There are no issues with word alignment and such.  That said, any caveats should probably be stated so someone else doesn't use a proposed solution inappropriately.

Comment: Use offsetof(). http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/offsetof/. Can get any wrong result imo.

Comment: this is not how union is supposed to be used and is very dangerous. If you are lucky, the compiler won't add any padding to your struct and it'll work.

Comment: @RedAlert you can "ask the compiler" not at add padding between the elements but whenever you see something like this you should assume that it isn't going to be portable.

Comment: Side remark: Anonymous structs inside unions/other classes are not allowed in standard C++. They're not even allowed in C99, finally C11 has added (official) support for them. g++ and clang++ support them as a language extension.

Comment: I think it would be a lot simpler to just have a normal struct; and then access it as `bytes` via a cast or a function call. The fewer non-standard constructs and hacks you use, the fewer headaches you will have down the track

Answer (score 7):

Just get rid of the union.  You can safely access any trivially-copyable structure as a byte array by casting its address to `char*`, and casting won't run afoul of the undefined behavior when you read from an inactive union member.

```
struct
{
    unsigned char a;
    unsigned char b;
    // ... Some other members ...
    unsigned char w;

    // array-style access
    unsigned char& operator[](size_t i)
    { return reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(this)[i]; }
} myStruct;
```

The reason that it's safe to cast in this manner is that `char` is a special exception from the strict aliasing restrictions.

For unions, the only special permission you get is for access to members which are "standard-layout structs which share a common initial sequence"... and an array unfortunately does not meet the criteria for a "standard-layout struct".  I would like to see that rule change to "standard-layout struct or aggregate", but in the current wording the union version isn't safe.

---

<strike>In C99, but not any version of C++, you could use a flexible array member, and not need to specify the size at all.</strike>

```
union
{
  struct
  {
    unsigned char a;
    unsigned char b;
    // ... Some other members ...
    unsigned char w;
  };
  unsigned char bytes[];
} myUnion;
```

Comment: yeah that seems more sane, ... or even just use a byte array

Comment: Looks like I'm not using C99, as I get the error "flexible array member in union" when trying the second solution.  The first apears to require C++ for the syntactic sugar, but the basic premise should work for me using `#define myStructBytes ((char *)myStruct)` or some such.  Thanks!

Comment: @gkimsey: I didn't test it, so possibly this is one of the places in C99 you can't you a flexible array member.  The fact that the compiler recognized it as that is pretty suggestive.  TonyK's version using a size of `1` is a reasonable workaround and probably works on most compilers, but I think it does break the rules.

Comment: n1570 6.7.2.1/18 "As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may
have an incomplete array type; this is called a *flexible array member*." So it seems indeed to be illegal. (Edit: ... saw the edit too late)

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
union
{
  struct
  {
    unsigned char a;
    unsigned char b;
    // ... Some other members ...
    unsigned char w;
  };
  unsigned char bytes[1];
} myUnion;
```

Comment: I had considered this, and assumed that then if I did `myUnion.bytes[2]` somewhere in my code the compiler would complain, but I just tried it and it doesn't.  I think I'll go with this, although it may not be very portable.

Comment: Here's an ideone using this solution if it's of benefit to anyone.
http://ideone.com/MDnXC6

Comment: @gkimsey: It's 100% portable. The expression `myUnion.bytes[2]` is the same as `*(myUnion.bytes+2)`, which is unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get around nameing the former anonymous structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the anonymous struct by using macros:

```c
#define ANON struct { unsigned char a; unsigned char b; }
#define ANON_SIZE sizeof(ANON)

union {
    ANON;
    unsigned char bytes[ANON_SIZE];
} myunion;
```